# How to design a performance test for e-commerce application with Jmeter where 10% of users make orders

Tags: jmeter, e-commerce, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I am conducting a performance test for an e-commerce demo application with Jmeter. I have managed to record the pages which a user navigates more but I want that 10% of total users which navigates the website to make orders.

I am aware that Jmeter interface is simplified and there is no way to play with these parameters.

Is this even do-able?

Thanks all!

I

I was expecting to find more on this topic

Answer (score 1):

JMeter provides [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) which allows to execute its children with the defined percentage from total number of requests.

[image]

Also there is [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter) plugin which is a little bit more flexible and convenient.